# My code below gives strange output.Explain

Tags: c

I am not able to figure out the output that i am getting from the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\5"); // This gives a different output
    return 0;
}
```

The output is ♣.

Comment: Someone please explain me the output of this code.The output is ♣.

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: What is it outputting? What were you *expecting*?

Comment: Does [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) help you understand why it is printing out a Club symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on you current encoding, you will get a special character when having something after backslash:

`"\5"` usually correspond to *enquiry* ("club") character which you can find from [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?names=2) for example.

If you really want to output **\5**, you'll need to put `"\\5"`.